# SQL Server GROUP BY multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

Let's assume I have in SQL Server the following table with only seven days available (SUN - SAT):
Orders

```
| Day | ProductType | Price |
| SUN | 1           | 10    |
| MON | 1           | 15    |
| MON | 2           | 20    |
| MON | 3           | 10    |
| TUE | 1           | 5     |
| TUE | 3           | 5     |
...
```

I need to group the data in a way so that to see the Total sum of Prices by each distinct Day and two groups of ProductType (= 1 and > 1):

```
| Day | FirstProductTypeTotal | RestProductsTypesTotal | GrandTotal |
| SUN | 10                    | 0                      | 10         |
| MON | 15                    | 30                     | 45         |
| TUE | 5                     | 5                      | 10         |
...
```

where FirstProductTypeTotal is ProductType = 1 and RestProductTypesTotal is ProductType > 1.

Is it possible to select this in one select instead of writing two different selects:

```
Select Day, SUM(Price) as FirstTotal from Orders where ProductType = 1 group by Day
```

and

```
Select Day, SUM(Price) as SecondTotal from Orders where ProductType > 1 group by Day
```

And then add FirstTotal and SecondTotal manually in the code to get the Grand total for each day of the week?

Comment: You can use case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CASE Expression

```
Select Day, SUM(CASE WHEN ProductType = 1 THE Price ELSE 0 END)  AS FirstTotal,
            SUM(CASE WHEN ProductType > 1 THE Price ELSE 0 END) AS SecondTotal,
            SUM(Price) AS GrandTotal
FROM Orders 
group by Day
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try conditional aggregation;

Sample data;

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders ([Day] varchar(10), ProductType int, Price int)
INSERT INTO #Orders ([Day],ProductType, Price)
VALUES
 ('SUN',1,10)
,('MON',1,15)
,('MON',2,20)
,('MON',3,10)
,('TUE',1,5)
,('TUE',3,5)
```

Query;

```
SELECT
    o.[Day]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.ProductType = 1 THEN o.Price ELSE 0 END) FirstTotal
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.ProductType > 1 THEN o.Price ELSE 0 END) SecondTotal
    ,SUM(o.Price) GrandTotal
FROM #Orders o
GROUP BY o.[Day]
```

Result

```
Day FirstTotal  SecondTotal GrandTotal
MON 15          30          45
SUN 10          0           10
TUE 5           5           10
```

You'd just need to sort out the ordering of the days because SQL Server by definition doesn't store the data in any particular order.